# How to color a list of names when the user entered one of them in richtextbox c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of names such as "John" , "Doe" .. etc
and i want to color them when the user entered one or more of them in richtextbox
and if the user delete a letter from the name (such as "john") the word's color
return to it's original color .

[this is experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAoV3.png)

```
  List<string> names = new List<string>
    {
        "john",
        "doe",
        "jack",
        "liza",
        "sandy",
        "sara"
    };



  private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(name))
            {
                var matchstring = Regex.Escape(name);
                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, matchstring))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                    richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.TextLength, 0);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = richTextBox1.ForeColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectAll();
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.TextLength, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no letter deleted in "john".

Comment: then why john's color is black and not red ??

Comment: With this approach, what happens if the text contains "john", but **not** "doe"?  First, "john" would change to red, but then **all** the text would become black again when "doe" is not found.  To fix this, set **all** the text to black (outside and **before** the loop), then change only matches to red within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of my comment above:

```
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0xB;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);

    List<string> names = new List<string>
    {
        "john",
        "doe",
        "jack",
        "liza",
        "sandy",
        "sara"
    };

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);

        int prevStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        int prevLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;

        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, Regex.Escape(name)))
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        richTextBox1.Select(prevStart, prevLength);

        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
        richTextBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

*The WM_SETREDRAW calls are necessary to reduce flicker as the RichTextBox is updated.  Without them, the flicker becomes really noticeable as the text gets longer and longer.